# How do I change the default country on the billing address form in Commerce 2?

Tags: 8, commerce

I want to set the default country when customers check out in Commerce 2.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the form display for the *Customer* **Profile Type**.

You can find it in the Admin menu under "Users", or go directly there by this path:

`/admin/config/people/profiles/manage/customer/form-display`

Then, on the widget for the address field, click the gear to set the default country.

Answer (score 1):

Path for me was: /admin/config/people/profile-types/manage/customer/fields

No gear to click, but there was an edit button:

[image]

Clicking the [edit] button dumps you off here: /admin/config/people/profile-types/manage/customer/fields/profile.customer.address

Scroll to the bottom and change this:
[image]
... to whatever you need the default country to be.